# Meteor client-side database query behavior

Tags: javascript, meteor-blaze

I noticed somehow weird behavior when followed Meteor introductory [tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app).
The tutorial used this snippet to query the database from the client-side code:

```
Template.body.helpers({
    tasks () {
        return Tasks.find({});
    },
});
```

It should return a cursor to the found collections then we can get the actual data using `.fetch()` and it works as expected.
but whenever i try to query in 'main.js' file on the client using something like this:

```
console.log(Tasks.find({}).fetch());
```

it always prints an empty array! any explanation ?

NOTE: when i query in the server-side code or the Template helper context (which is considered a client-side code) it prints all the data in the database perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client-side collection is probably empty at the time the query is evaluated. Top-level statements main.js can run before the client receives all if its collections data from the server.